# putting query in exec

Tags: sql, exec, dynamic-sql

```
SET @count = 0
SET @select = ''
WHILE @count < @c_count
BEGIN
    SET @count = @count+1.
    SET @select = @select+'cinema'+cast(@count AS VARCHAR)+'+'
END
SET @select = SUBSTRING(@select, 1, LEN(@select) - 1)
select @qty = qty from #qty
SET @buffer = 'UPDATE #table SET total_sales = '+@select
PRINT @buffer
EXEC(@buffer)

update #table set total_quantity = tq.qty from #table t inner join #qty tq on t.pkey =tq.id
```

here's my code in updating #table, i am having a problem putting the last update in @buffer,
help me pls.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 1):

My first question whenever I see someone doing this, is WHY?

If you are building up a SQL String and then trying to execute it, you are probably doing it wrong, and more than likely, you don't know enough of what you are doing that you can prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: i just want to know how to use exec().

Comment: Well, what does your PRINT output?